# What's the best way to model Custom Object for Document ID in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Say I have a collection of 'Users', and am happy for their ID to be the generated Firestore documentId, something like:

```
Users Collection
    GENERATED_FIRESTORE_ID1:
        name: "User 1 name"
        ...: etc.
    GENERATED_FIRESTORE_ID2:
        name: "User 2 name"
         ...: etc."
```

and I am adding them, and retrieving them with a custom object (I'm using Android at the moment but the question I guess is more generalistic). I don't want to have an extra "id" field in the document, just use the `document.getId()` method to get the generated firestore ID.

Is there a correct way to map a POJO to not have an indivual ID field, but when querying set it for application usage? I am doing it using the @Exclude annotation as follows:

```
public class User {

// as a side question, do I need @exclude on the field or just the getter?
@Exclude
String uId;

String name;
String email;
//... additional fields as normal

public User() {
}

@Exclude
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.displayName = name;
}

//... etc. etc.
```

}

and then I create the User object and set its ID as follows:

```
 for (DocumentSnapshot doc : documentSnapshots) {
     User user = doc.toObject(User.class);
     user.setId(doc.getId());
     users.add(user );
 }
```

This works fine, and apologies if this is indeed the way, but I'm new to FireStore (am loving it) and want to make sure I'm doing it right. I just wondered if there was a way this would all be automatic, without @Exclude and then manually setting the ID after `doc.toObject(MyCustomObject.class)`

Comment: Did you figure anything out in these 2 months? Because I have the same question.

Comment: Not found anything out yet. I thought a good way the Firebase team could implement it would be some sort of `@ID` annotation, that behaves similar to exclude (in that it doesn't add an additional duplicate id field in the document) but when retrieving from database it automatically populates the document Id to that field. A subtle change, would only save one line of code (the `user.setId()`) part, but would look better semantically.

Comment: Ok, but the @Exclude annotation on the getter method is enough, right? Is there any additional benefit in adding it to the field declaration or the setter method?

Comment: as far as I know, you don't need `@exclude` on any of the setter methods (in fact may even break things when retrieving)... I haven't really tested what it does on the field, I think i just like it as it shows my model a little clearer

Comment: OK thanks a lot for answering

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is now an Annotation for this -

You could simply use

`@DocumentId
String uID`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentId.html

Comment: Hoorah! I think they should credit me, my first comment in the question above is basically what they ended up doing :-D

Comment: Haha, yep pretty much!

Comment: Thanks for this link :) great!